# UserControl for different data-objects

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Let's say I have the following two classes in my model-folder:

```
public class Simple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Display { get; set; }

    public double Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Extended : Simple
{
    public double Value2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To display a collection of `Simple` I've created a `UserControl` which looks like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,2"/>
           <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Id">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Display" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Display">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value1" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Value1">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The usage of this `UserControl` looks like:

```
<local:SEControl DataContext="{Binding Simples}"/>
```

Now I want to display a collection of `Extended`-Objects. My approach would now be to write another `UserControl` which just have two columns more than the other one.

My question now is: Is there a way to just write one `UserControl` which can handle `Simple` and `Extended`?

I also thought about a `DataTemplate`, but there I have to duplicate the logic too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Visibility.

Add the extended columns as here :

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding IsExtended, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Hidden}" Header="Test" Width="*" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and using a converter you can switch whenever you need to show or not these columns.
So, when you change the ItemSource in order to contain Extended items, change also the IsExtended property to true and vice-versa.